# Understanding the shape of skimage.view_in_windows

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

After applying the `view_in_windows` from `skimage` on an rgb image `(221,95,3)` I'm left with an `output` shape of `(217, 91, 1, 5, 5, 3)`.

I assume that `output.shape[3]` and `output.shape[4]` are the height and width of the window, whilst `output.shape[5]` is the number of original channels.

Can anyone explain what the first two numbers are in the `output.shape`, and how I would be able to get a shape corresponding to `(No. windows, height, width, No. channels)` since my task is related to preparing inputs for image classification.

All I have so far:

````
step = 1
window = 5
output = view_as_windows(input_image, (window, window, 3), step=step)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The first two numbers are the number of windows along the height and width of the image. Because the windows have shape (5, 5), you can't fit 221 windows along the rows, you can only fit 217. Ditto for the columns.

As a one dimensional analog, if you have `np.arange(4)` as your input, and you want a sliding window of size 3, you can only fit two windows, (0, 1, 2) and (1, 2, 3).

You can either pad your image with `np.pad` at the beginning to get the same number of windows as you have pixels, or just make do with the reduced image size.

As for reshaping, in this case it's easy:

```py
step = 1
window = 5
window_shape = (window, window, 3)
output_raw = view_as_windows(input_image, window_shape, step)
output = output.reshape((-1,) + window_shape)
```

Note, however, that while `output_raw` uses [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) to generate a *view* into the array with zero copying, the stride tricks *can't represent* `output` (with reshaping), so you will be creating an array of `np.product(output_raw.shape)` elements, in this case ~1.5M. This can get out of hand really fast.